# Optimal way to set up a complex WooCommerce store

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a store that sells cheese and meat. I would like to set up a WooCommerce store and I am looking for some input as to whether it would be feasible to use the import tool given the complexity of my product catalogue.

The store has products for which there are multiple vendors and unit sizes. 
For example, we sell a bison steak from three different vendors in two unit sizes.

We would code this in our offline ordering system as six products:

- BIS-VEN1-US1
- BIS-VEN1-US2
- BIS-VEN2-US1
- BIS-VEN2-US2
- BIS-VEN3-US1
- BIS-VEN3-US2

Each of these products could have a different price.

I know that WooCommerce has an option to set up variable products with variations that should allow me to set up products like this but I am not quite sure how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but stackOverFlow is about coding, not about software settings and tutorials, so not the right place for this question. You should read the official documentation, search web tutorials and try yourself many times until you will get what you expect.